# How to import qTox profile into uTox?

Tags: configuration, tox, qtox, utox

I want to switch from qTox to uTox, I have a qTox profile, is there any way to import this profile into uTox? I have it in `.tox` format. My uTox version is `0.9.7` running on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 with GNOME 3.20.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have to go into `~/.config/tox/` and replace the existing `tox_save.tox` with the `.tox` file you exported from qTox.

It might be a good idea to rename the original `tox_save.tox` to something like `tox_save_backup.tox` in case something goes wrong.

uTox should then start using the profile you had on qTox.